# Unable to find headers of jpg while reading a raw disk image (dd)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jpeg

I am reading a raw disk image using python 3. My task is to retrieve (carve) jpgs as individual files from the disk image. As I know header pattern (`\xd8\xff\xe0` or `\xd8\xff\xe1`) of jpg. I want to know where I get this while reading file.

```
fobj = open('carve.dd', 'rb')
data = fobj.read(32)

while data != '':
 head_loc = findheader(data)
 print(head_loc)
 data = fobj.read(32)

def findheader(data) :  # to find header in each 32 bytes of data of raw disk image
 for i in range(0, len(data) - 3) :
  if data[i] == b'\xff' :
    if data[i+1:i+4] == b'\xd8\xff\xe0' or data[i+1:i+4] == b'\xd8\xff\xe1' :
      return i
 return -1
```

The same code is working fine in Python 2. In Python 2, I am able to get headers in just a few seconds from image. Can someone help me out, what is the problem in Python 3?

This code snippet is actually from this https://github.com/darth-cheney/JPEG-Recover/blob/master/jpegrecover2.py
This runs fine in Python 2 but not in Python 3. **Please forget about inconsistent tab error when you run the code in link**. I again retyped in VS code.

Comment: There's nothing obvious that would make the code fail in Python 3 that I can see. Can you post a link to some test data that can be used to reproduce the problem? It doesn't need to be the entire disk image file.

Comment: This link has dd image . Please use this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QP0HYEuycvyz5hj3zOfuMf1mNoTgNVkz

Comment: It does not work in Python 3 because `if data[i] == b'\xff':` fails. It must be `if data[i] == 0xff:` – the *type* of these data bytes is `int`, whereas in Python 2 it is `str`. If you change the type of `data` to a `bytearray`, then you can use the same comparison in both 2 and 3 (the one with `0xff`).

Comment: True that data[i] is int. Even if I try bytes(data[i]) == b'\xff', nowhere its matching in Python 3 but actually there is such pattern found when run in python 2.

Comment: manivarma: It's likely still failing for a similar reason — namely that the type of `data[i+1:i+4]` is different from `b'\xd8\xff\xe0'` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Like the old saying goes, I've got some bad news and some good news. The bad is I can't figure out why your code doesn't work the same in both version 2 and version 3 of Python.

The good is that I was able to reproduce the problem using the sample data you provided, but—more importantly—able to devise something that not only works consistently in both versions, it's likely *much* faster because it doesn't use a `for` loop to search through each chunk of data looking for the .jpg header patterns.

```
from __future__ import print_function

LIMIT = 100000  # Number of chunks (for testing).
CHUNKSIZE = 32  # Bytes.
HDRS = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0', b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1'
IMG_PATH = r'C:\vols\Files\Temp\carve.dd.002'

print('Searching...')
with open(IMG_PATH, 'rb') as file:
    chunk_index = 0
    found = 0
    while True:
        data = file.read(CHUNKSIZE)
        if not data:
            break

        # Search for each of the headers in each chunk.
        for hdr in HDRS:
            offset = 0
            while offset < (CHUNKSIZE - len(hdr)):
                try:
                    head_loc = data[offset:].index(hdr)
                except ValueError:  # Not found.
                    break
                found += 1
                file_offset = chunk_index*CHUNKSIZE + head_loc
                print('found: #{} at {:,}'.format(found, file_offset))
                offset += (head_loc + len(hdr))

        chunk_index += 1
        if LIMIT and (chunk_index == LIMIT): break  # Stop after this many chunks.

print('total found {}'.format(found))
```

Comment: If this pattern b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0' exists twice then it returns for first pattern it finds and returns and leaves second index where pattern is there

Comment: @manivarmaindukuri: It does the same thing that your code does—namely find the _first_ instance of either header in the data chunk if one exists.The main thing I was trying to illustrate was a fast way to search for patterns that works in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: It is working but what is the difference between my code and yours . You used a function and I used iteration  and my code is not working and yours is working. Anyhow Thank you so much

Comment: @manivarmaindukuri: I've modified it to find multiple header ocurrences in each chunk.

Comment: One more help is I have to retrieve jpg files from disk image. I used code in this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QP0HYEuycvyz5hj3zOfuMf1mNoTgNVkz written in Python 2. I changed it to Python 3 but its going into infinite loop. Can you please help me in this assignment to make it work in Python 3. Here is my code in Python 3 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L3PBJeOKHeamZ2252CEBZ3QqU9w8TSt9   . Comments are written wherever required. Please ask if you have doubts. Thank you, Sir

Comment: For Python 3, the `while data != '' :` needs to be  `while data != b'' :`. Using `while data :` would work in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. It is working fine. You really helped me a lot.